# A-Frame A-Entity Depth Value stuck at default 1-2 no matter what I type

Tags: aframe, webvr

Using Depth, to give a wall thickness of 8 does not work, I even tried setting it to 32. it is still flat. A-Box lets me set depth with no problem, A-Entity DOES NOT.

I made A j_Fiddle to show the problem:
    https://jsfiddle.net/RonK/tjfwhdsd/16/

`depth=32` or depth=8 will not change the display.

The red Brick can be resized, and it's depth on the z axis set to "8".
The Wall has it's depth set to 32, and is still around 1/3 the depth
of the red brick.

Any Clue how to fix this?

I also tried:
`wallfrnt.setAttribute("scale"",{x:1, y:1, z:2});`
with no visible effect.

Comment: I should have said, using a-entity instead of a-box.

Answer (score 0):

I've forked your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ccea7fgf/1/. There were some issues inside your code:

1. On this line you've forgot to close the tags

   ```
   <a-entity position="0 54 0"</a-entity>
   ```

   Use this instead:

   ```
   <a-entity position="0 54 0"></a-entity>
   ```
2. The floor must have a position of 0 in X, 0 in Y and 144 in Z direction

---

For set the attribute, you must use this code:

```
wallfrnt.setAttribute("scale", "1 1 2");
```

This code is wrong

```
wallfrnt.setAttribute("scale"",{x:1, y:1, z:2});
```

Because

1. You use `"scale""` instead of `"scale"`.
2. Values of attributes must been given by a string that represents the object `{ x, y, z }`.

---

For give the wall a depth, I've found that's better to use an [`a-box`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/primitives/a-box.html) instead of a `a-entity`. The `src` attribute must be `#WhiteBricks` and the attributes `width`, `height` and `depth` must bee separated.

```
<a-box src="#WhiteBricks" width="288" height="108" depth="320" position="0 54 -160"/>
```

Here you could find my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ccea7fgf/3/

Comment: Ah, thank you, the double quote keep popping up, my editor adds them automatically when I'm typing, and also closes tags when I use </> it just fills them in blindly.. constant nuisance. the curly brackets {} I used because I saw them used that way on one of the faqs, but, even in your fork, I don't see the walls being any thicker..?

Comment: Had floor set to 0-0 but kept appearing in the middle of the wall, this was prob due to the typo's I had missed and being improperly closed. Thanks for that part.

Comment: By switching back to Box, instead of entity, it now has depth, but the texture stopped tiling, and is now stretched. I was repeating the texture to make the white bricks roughly the size of the red one. The red is 16" x 8" x 8" , the size of a standard cement block used for construction. (minus   1/8" on each side for mortar joint.)

Comment: when I add the semicolon after the texture name in box to add the arguments I added in entity, it crashes the whole page. Entity is accepting the changes, whereas box will not accept them. I see docs and tuts everywhere where someone changes one of these things, but none where BOTH are successfully made to work with a resource cited.